# Howto process Ajax returned data using rails3.1 and jquery

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ujs

I'm using the data-remote along with data-URL to make an Ajax call via jquery ujs and it is working.

However, I can't understand how I'm to process the returned value.

For example, I have a controller action which returns some HTML - how do I attach a JS function (I presume) to replace the HTML in an existing div when the Ajax call finishes? I've set data-type to :html btw.

I can see the HTML is being returned by sniffing the network traffic.

I've got it to work by writing my own Ajax call (rather than using jquerys ujs version) but it feels as though I've reinvented the wheel - but I can't find how to use jquerys data-remote to make the call for me, and to then have it update a div (for example).

Thanks,

Ian

Answer (score 0):

i presume that you have a button with the id "button" and a div with the id "add_some_content"

```
$("#button").click( function(){
  $.get("some_random_url", function(data) {
    $("#add_some_content").html(data);
  });
});
```

or as jxpx777 pointed out:

```
$("#button").click(function(){ 
  $("#add_some_content").load("some_random_url");
});
```

if you now press on the button, an ajax get request for your url is made. the answer from that page is attached to the div.

Comment: Using `.load()` will make it even shorter. `$("#button").click(function(){ $("#add_some_content").load("some_random_url"); });`

Comment: I'm referring to using the jquery-ujs code in which if you add data-remote and data-url it does the call behind the scenes - which seems the idea of UJS in that code is not inline with the HTML.